# Fit a wider table into PDF

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

This is in continuation to the question asked in github, Fit a wider table into PDF #261.

I'm reusing the same method(doc.autoTable) to create PDF out of different HTML inputs.
So, If I define the column style of 0th column as columnWidth: 'wrap', then the same style will be applied for all the HTML tables that invoke this particular method.

I'm not sure If I can follow long text example, as both the column names & table body are coming from HTML page directly. Whereas in the long text example, I'm seeing the column names being declared/defined as shown below

```
var columnsLong = getColumns().concat([
        {title: "Title with\nlinebreak", dataKey: "text2"},
        {title: "Long text column", dataKey: "text"},
    ]);
```

Now there are 2 questions.
1. I dont want to apply 'WRAP' for all the columns, as the table gets cut.
2. Need to apply 'wrap' for certain columns alone by mentioning the column name that comes from HTML/GSP page.

This is my code

```
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson($(".printReportsCaveat")[0]); 
    doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
                         columnStyles : {'Plant':{columnWidth: 'wrap'},
                             'Mine':{columnWidth: 'wrap'},
                             0:{textColor: [0,105,170]}
                         },
                          margin: {top: 55, bottom : 110},
                          headerStyles: {
                             overflow: 'linebreak',
                             // columnWidth: 'auto',
                              halign: 'center'
                             },
                            styles : {
                                 overflow: 'linebreak',
                                  halign: 'center',
                                  fontSize: 8
                            },
                            createdCell: function(cell, data) {
                                var group = $('#groupByValue').val();
                                addColorToCell(group, level3Flag, level2Flag, data, cell);                          
                            },

                            addPageContent : function(data) {
                                printHeadNFoot(doc, userDtl, data);                             
                            },
                            drawCell: function(cell, data) {
                                designCell(data,doc);                             
                            },
                      });
```

Kindly help!

Comment: Please be informed, I'm using doc.autoTableHtmlToJson.

Comment: If you want all columns to wrap you can use `styles: { columnWidth: 'wrap' }` instead?

Comment: Have you looked at the long text example?

Comment: And you should probably edit your question to be more generic so it can be understood by and help more people.

Comment: Thanks for the timely response Simson! If I use styles: { columnWidth: 'wrap' }, then the table gets cut as I have more number of columns. And for some reason, I couldnt apply columnWidth: 'wrap' for 0th column alone. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Not with the info provided in the question unfortunately. Rewrite it to be more generic and provide some code and I can take a look at it again.

Comment: I have edited my question. Pls see if it is understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly you can try referencing a specific column by index instead of by key. I.e. `columnWidth: {0: columnWidth: 'wrap'}`.

Comment: Yes, you got my point. For some reason, column width is not getting applied for 0th column alone, whereas I could do the same for the remaining columns. But to note, I could do this coloring 0:{textColor: [255,0,0]} on 0th column itself.

Comment: I'm able to get the column in 0th position to look proper, only if I adjust the width of all the remaining columns. doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
columnStyles : {0:{columnWidth: 'wrap'},
1:{columnWidth: 50},  2:{columnWidth: 30},
3:{columnWidth: 30},4:{columnWidth: 30},
5:{columnWidth: 30},6:{columnWidth: 30},
7:{columnWidth: 30}, 8:{columnWidth: 50},9:{columnWidth: 50},
10:{columnWidth: 50},11:{columnWidth: 30}12:{columnWidth: 30},
13:{columnWidth: 30},14:{columnWidth: 30},15:{columnWidth: 30},
 0:{textColor: [255,0,0]}
      },